# Form action not working with table inside form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a table inside a form like this:

```html
    <form action="file.php" id="myform" method="POST">
            <div class="table-responsive ">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="tblDetalle">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Quant.</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody">
                        <?php
                        if(!isset($_SESSION['products'])){
                        }else{
                            foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $product=>$details){    
                                echo '
                                    <tr class="txtMult">
                                        <th scope = "row">'.$details["code_product"].'</th>
                                        <th scope = "row">'.$details["name_product"].'</th>
                                        <td><input class="val2" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
                                        <td class="val1">'.$details["price"].'</td>
                                        <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
                                    </tr>                                
                                ';
                            };
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                            <td colspan=4>Total <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My actual problem is that submit botton isn't working, no actions are taken when I click button.
My idea is send all content of table to file.php through POST method.

There's a script that updates last  with price*quantity but I don't think that problem lives there.

```js
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
        function multInputs() {
            var mult = 0;
            // for each row:
            $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
                // get the values from this row:
                var $val1 = parseInt($('.val1', this).text())
                var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
                var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
                $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
                mult += $total;
            });
            $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Anybody can help? :)

Comment: In line 13, change <tbody"> to  <tbody> and try again

Comment: Within the PHP loop you are repeating the `id="quantity"` ~ IDs must be unique.

Comment: The input element `quantity` should be named `quantity[]` if you hope to send more than one value for it. It looks like that is the only input element though so no way to determine which quantity refers to which product as far as I can tell

Comment: you can not get whole table through post form, you can get only input field values via this method and then you  need to arrange table on that file.php page with post form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the small typo in the HTML is corrected and without your PHP logic ( no way to test that - hence hardcoded dummy data ) what you could do would be to use Javascript to send the form data rather than rely upon a regular form submission as was failing for you here. HTML content and text will not be sent via the form - only content from `input` elements so your form would submit a single field called `quantity` which is not what you want.

The following uses `fetch` to send the `formData` to your intended PHP script.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function multInputs() {
        var mult = 0;
        $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
            var $val1 = parseInt($('.val1', this).text())
            var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
            var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
            $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
            mult += $total;
        });
        $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
        return mult;
    }
    
    
    const submithandler=(e)=>{
      // stop the regular `submit`
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // add form data to these variables
      let fd=new FormData();
      let payload=[];
      
      // process the contents of the HTML table to populate the formData object
      $("tr.txtMult").each(function(){
        let item={
          code:this.firstElementChild.textContent,
          name:this.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.textContent,
          value:$('.val2', this).val()
        };
        
        // convert object to string
        payload.push( JSON.stringify(item) );
      });
      
      fd.set('payload', payload );
      
      // send the request
      fetch( document.getElementById('myform').action,{ method:'post', body:fd })
        .then( r=>r.text() )
        .then( text=>{
          alert( text )// do stuff with results?
        })
        .catch( err=>console.log('Error:%o',err) )
    };
    
    
    $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
    $('[type="submit"]').click(submithandler);
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="file.php" id="myform" method="POST">
            <div class="table-responsive ">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="tblDetalle">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Quant.</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                    <!-- Hardcoded example data -->

                        <tr class="txtMult">
                            <th scope = "row">Code ABC-1</th>
                            <th scope = "row">Name - 1</th>
                            <td><input class="val2" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
                            <td class="val1">100</td>
                            <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr class="txtMult">
                            <th scope = "row">Code ABC-2</th>
                            <th scope = "row">Name - 2</th>
                            <td><input class="val2" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
                            <td class="val1">200</td>
                            <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr class="txtMult">
                            <th scope = "row">Code ABC-3</th>
                            <th scope = "row">Name - 3</th>
                            <td><input class="val2" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"></td>
                            <td class="val1">300</td>
                            <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                            <td colspan=4>Total <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                
                <input type="submit" />
                
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for to do. Thanks professor!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use tables inside forms but I think you're approach is wrong. you can put a table inside a form or vice versa, and it is often useful to do so. But you need to understand what you are doing.

Tables and forms can be nested either way. But if you put forms into tables, each form must be completely included into a single table cell (one TD element in practice). Thereby the forms are each completely independent.
So try putting the form inside the table cell which requires the input